# Register jQuery event in trusted Angular injected HTML

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an Angular app with injected legacy HTML. I need to bypass sanitization, because it strips styles from elements.

```
<div class="legacy" [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html)"></div>
```

But then I fail to register jQuery event for links in previously injected HTML:

```
  setTimeout(() => {         
      $('.legacy a:not([href^="http"])').off('click').on('click', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('success');
      });          
    });
```

While debugging in browser I can see jQuery event registration being called on link elements, but no event is registered on element unless I remove sanitizer bypass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I move sanitization from template to code, it works.

```
this.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
```

```
<div class="legacy" [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```